# TestNG Dataprovider priority

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-annotation-test

I have a TestNG Dataprovider tests like below:

**Input.csv**

```
id,priority,testData,...
T1,1,someData,...
T1,0,someData,...
```

**Reader**

```
@DataProvider(name="abc")
public Object[][] readData(){
  // Logic to read csv file.
}
```

**Test**

```
@Test(dataprovider="abc")
public void test(){
  // Test code.
}
```

There are many input files and each test contains a priority. I would like to run the tests which has priority 1 alone.

Without data providers, I'm able to filter the tests using IMethodInterceptor like below.

```
class interceptor implements IMethodInterceptor {

  @Override
  public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> instance, 
   ITestContext context){
     for(IMethodInstance method:instance){
        if(method.getMethod().getPriority()==1){
          // Add in new list and return it.
        }
     }
  }
}
```

**Sample Test:**

```
@Test(priority=1)
public void testA(){
 print("A");
}

@Test(priority=2)
public void testB(){
 print("B");
}

Output: A
```

**Since the priorities are dynamic for dataproviders, I'm unable to filter the tests based on the priority**.

Other tests should not be executed instead of SKIPPED.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!. TestNG provides `IDataProviderInterceptor` similar to `IMethodInterceptor` to handle dataprovider tests.

**Sample:**

```
public class Interceptor implements IDataProviderInterceptor {
     
   @Override
   public Iterator<Object[]> intercept(Iterator<Object[]> original, 
                                       IDataProviderMethod dataproviderMethod,
                                       ITestNGMethod method,
                                       ITestContext context) {

      // Typecast original object and filter priority.
   }
}
```